# Как преднамеренно выйти из условия после обработки предыдущего

Tags: java, android

**Цель:** выполняется определенный запрос (запрос на ответ). Если ответ верный - переход к следующему вопросу.

Получается, что одновременно отрабатывают все условия и обработчик кнопки отрабатывает действие с предыдущего условия.Как сделать последовательный опрос?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnVersion3:

            tvCountry.setText(R.string.poland);
            btnVersion1.setText(R.string.krakow);
            btnVersion2.setText(R.string.milan);
            btnVersion3.setText(R.string.minsk);
            btnVersion4.setText(R.string.warsaw);
            break;
        default:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            break;
    }


    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnVersion4:

            tvCountry.setText(R.string.italy);
            btnVersion1.setText(R.string.rome);
            btnVersion2.setText(R.string.milan);
            btnVersion3.setText(R.string.kiev);
            btnVersion4.setText(R.string.oslo);
            break;
        default:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            break;
    }

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnVersion2:

            tvCountry.setText(R.string.spain);
            btnVersion1.setText(R.string.madrid);
            btnVersion2.setText(R.string.milan);
            btnVersion3.setText(R.string.barcelona);
            btnVersion4.setText(R.string.rome);
            break;
        default:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Во-первых, какие циклы? Во-вторых, зачем 3 `switch` здесь?

Comment: пусть будет цикл if или switch ошибка одна и та же,это неважно. Получается так, что при выполнении кода обрабатывается нажатие кнопки но не только в необходимом цикле, а и в других.

Comment: Например, на вопрос 2+2, есть четыре варианта ответа (1, 2, 3, 4), соответственно,если нажать на ответ 4, все хорошо, переход к следующему вопросу. если 1 или 2 или 3, то выбивается ошибка. (так должно быть, НО)

Comment: Переход к следующему вопросу я реализовал методом setText(), таким образом если ответом было 4, то следующий вопрос, например, 3+4, варианты ответов (2,3,4,7), и еще один вопрос 5+3 и варианты ответа (2,8,5,3). сам вопрос это view - TextView, а варианты ответа - это кнопки  Button. И получается так, что при нажатии на четвертую кнопку в первом и во втором вопросе приведет нас к третьему вопросу, а должно перейти ко второму вопросу. Наверно все сильно закручено, если непонятно, попробую объяснить получше.

Comment: Все это [вот так делается](https://github.com/jameskbride/). Описание в книге Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2015

Comment: `if` и `switch` это не циклы.

Comment: спасибо, оговорился, условия

Answer (score 2):

Вы конечно можете хардкорно все позабивать, на каждый вопрос и каждый вариант ответа что-то прописать. Но лучше же сделать универсальный вариант. Кратко логика:

- Есть счетчик вопросов, массив с вопросами, ответами.
- Берете из массива вопрос, ждете ответ.
- В `onClick` проверяете, правильная ли кнопка, которую нажал пользователь для ответа.
- Если ответ правильный - молодец, следующий вопрос, если нет - не молодец, следующий вопрос/проигрыш.

Навскидку:

```
ArrayList<String[]> qaArr = new ArrayList<>();
private int counter = 0;
...
{
    ...
    //Допустим, вручную добавляем все вопросы, ответы:
    qaArr.add(new String[]{"Вопрос","Ответ1", "Ответ2", "Ответ3", "Ответ4", "1"});
    ...
    setQuestionData();
}
//Устанавливаем вопрос/ответы
private void setQuestionData() {
    tvCountry.setText(qaArr.get(counter)[0]);
    btnVersion1.setText(qaArr.get(counter)[1]);
    btnVersion2.setText(qaArr.get(counter)[2]);
    btnVersion3.setText(qaArr.get(counter)[3]);
    btnVersion4.setText(qaArr.get(counter)[4]);
}
//Нажатие
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String answer = "4";
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnVersion1:
            answer = "1"
            break;
        case R.id.btnVersion2:
            answer = "2"
            break;
        case R.id.btnVersion3:
            answer = "3"
            break;
       default:
            break;
    }
    if(qaArr.get(counter)[5].equals(answer)) {
        //правильно
    } else {
        //неправильно
    }
    counter++;
    if(counter < qaArr.size()) {
        setQuestionData();
    } else {
        //Вопросов больше не имею
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, за развернутый ответ. То,что надо!

Comment: @V.Ch если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галкой.